# Build class that implement a memory-leak check

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiler

I'd like to find memory-leaks in my applications.
I would try to find leaks without install software or extensions.

Following this link

https://michaelscodingspot.com/5-techniques-to-avoid-memory-leaks-by-events-in-c-net-you-should-know/

i Tried to build my own class.

Here the code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Use: lanch instance of the class
''' - Friend memorytest As New MemoryLeakTest(MemoryLeakTest.memorySize.MBytes)
''' Parameters:
''' - MemorySize (MBytes, KBytes, Bytes)
''' - AlertSize (set Alert to True if the increment of the new memory usage it's >)
''' 
''' And then, to record the memory usage of a step
''' - memorytest.NewStep("abc")
''' 
''' To record and get the memory usage of every step:
''' - PrintMethod(memorytest.NewStep("abc").ToString)
''' 
''' To record a step and get only results with an Increment of the Memory used > initial alertSize setting:
''' - If memoryTest.NewStepConditioned("abc") Then PrintMethod(memoryTest.LastStep)
''' 
''' To get the sum of all Memory increments by step:
''' - PrintMethod(memorytest.GetMemoryUsedByStep("abc"))
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Friend Class MemoryLeakTest
    Sub New(Optional ByVal newMemorySize As memorySize = memorySize.KBytes, Optional ByVal newAlertSize As Integer = 0)
        _memorySize = newMemorySize
        _alertSize = newAlertSize
    End Sub

    Private _memorySize As memorySize
    Private _alertSize As Integer
    Private _Priority As Integer
    Private _Id As Integer
    Private _Title As String
    Private _MaxWorkingSet As IntPtr
    Private _MinWorkingSet As IntPtr
    Private _ProcessName As String
    Private _StartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Private _PriorityClass As System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass

    Private _MemorySteps As New List(Of MemoryStep)

    Friend Function NewStep(ByVal _Step As String) As String
        CallGC()
        CheckMemoryStep(_Step)
        'CallGC()
        Return _MemorySteps(_MemorySteps.Count - 1).ToString
    End Function

    Friend Function NewStepConditioned(ByVal _Step As String) As Boolean
        CallGC()
        CheckMemoryStep(_Step)
        'CallGC()
        Return _MemorySteps(_MemorySteps.Count - 1).Alert
    End Function
    Friend Function LastStep() As String
        Return _MemorySteps(_MemorySteps.Count - 1).ToString
    End Function

    Friend Function GetMemoryUsedByStep(ByVal NewStep As String) As String
        Dim MemoryUsed As List(Of MemoryStep) = _MemorySteps.FindAll(Function(x) x._step = NewStep)
        Return MemoryUsed.Sum(Function(x) x._inc_WorkingSet).ToString & " " & _memorySize.ToString
    End Function

    Friend Sub CallGC()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        'GC.Collect()
    End Sub
    Friend Sub CheckMemoryStep(ByVal newStep As String)
        Using cp As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess
            If IsNothing(_StartInfo) Then
                _Priority = cp.BasePriority
                _Id = cp.Id
                _Title = cp.MainWindowTitle
                _MaxWorkingSet = cp.MaxWorkingSet
                _MinWorkingSet = cp.MinWorkingSet
                _PriorityClass = cp.PriorityClass
                _ProcessName = cp.ProcessName
                _StartInfo = cp.StartInfo
                _MemorySteps.Add(New MemoryStep(newStep, cp, _memorySize, _alertSize))
            Else
                _MemorySteps.Add(New MemoryStep(newStep, cp, _memorySize, _alertSize, _MemorySteps(_MemorySteps.Count - 1)))
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Friend Class MemoryStep
        Sub New(ByVal newStep As String, ByVal cp As System.Diagnostics.Process, ByVal memSize As memorySize, ByVal alertSize As Integer, Optional ByVal oldStep As MemoryStep = Nothing)
            _memorySize = memSize
            _step = newStep
            _NonPagedSystemMemory = CLng(cp.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _PagedMemory = CLng(cp.PagedMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _PagedSystemMemory = CLng(cp.PagedSystemMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _PeakPagedMemory = CLng(cp.PeakPagedMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _PeakVirtualMemory = CLng(cp.PeakVirtualMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _PeakWorkingSet = CLng(cp.PeakWorkingSet64 / memSize)
            _PrivateMemory = CLng(cp.PrivateMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _VirtualMemory = CLng(cp.VirtualMemorySize64 / memSize)
            _WorkingSet = CLng(cp.WorkingSet64 / memSize)

            If Not IsNothing(oldStep) Then
                With oldStep
                    _inc_NonPagedSystemMemory = _NonPagedSystemMemory - ._NonPagedSystemMemory
                    _inc_PagedMemory = _PagedMemory - ._PagedMemory
                    _inc_PagedSystemMemory = _PagedSystemMemory - ._PagedSystemMemory
                    _inc_PeakPagedMemory = _PeakPagedMemory - ._PeakPagedMemory
                    _inc_PeakVirtualMemory = _PeakVirtualMemory - ._inc_PeakVirtualMemory
                    _inc_PeakWorkingSet = _PeakWorkingSet - ._PeakWorkingSet
                    _inc_PrivateMemory = _PrivateMemory - ._PrivateMemory
                    _inc_VirtualMemory = _VirtualMemory - ._VirtualMemory
                    _inc_WorkingSet = _WorkingSet - ._WorkingSet
                End With
            End If

            If _inc_WorkingSet > alertSize Then
                Alert = True
            End If
        End Sub
        Private _NonPagedSystemMemory As Long
        Private _PagedMemory As Long
        Private _PagedSystemMemory As Long
        Private _PeakPagedMemory As Long
        Private _PeakVirtualMemory As Long
        Private _PeakWorkingSet As Long
        Private _PrivateMemory As Long
        Private _VirtualMemory As Long
        Private _WorkingSet As Long
        Private _memorySize As memorySize

        Private _inc_NonPagedSystemMemory As Long
        Private _inc_PagedMemory As Long
        Private _inc_PagedSystemMemory As Long
        Private _inc_PeakPagedMemory As Long
        Private _inc_PeakVirtualMemory As Long
        Private _inc_PeakWorkingSet As Long
        Private _inc_PrivateMemory As Long
        Private _inc_VirtualMemory As Long
        Friend _inc_WorkingSet As Long

        Friend _step As String
        Friend Alert As Boolean = False

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            ToString = _step & vbTab & "memory usage: " & _WorkingSet.ToString & " " & _memorySize.ToString
            If _inc_WorkingSet < 0 Then
                ToString += " (- " & -_inc_WorkingSet.ToString & " " & _memorySize.ToString & ")"
            Else
                ToString += " (+ " & _inc_WorkingSet.ToString & " " & _memorySize.ToString & ")"
            End If
            Return ToString
        End Function
    End Class

    Enum memorySize
        MBytes = 1024000
        KBytes = 1024
        [Bytes] = 1
    End Enum
End Class
```

The use of this class should be:

```
Class Test
    Friend memorytest As New MemoryLeakTest(MemoryLeakTest.memorySize.MBytes)

    Sub RunTest()
        memorytest.NewStep("Start")

        Method_1()
        WriteToTextBox(memorytest.NewStep("Method_1").ToString)

        Method_2()
        WriteToTextBox(memorytest.NewStep("Method_2").ToString)

        Method_3()
        If memoryTest.NewStepConditioned("Method_3") Then WriteToTextBox(memoryTest.LastStep)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_1()
        'Do something
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_2()
        'Do something
    End Sub

    Private Function Method_3()
        'Do something
    End Function

    Private Sub WriteToTextBox(ByVal msg As String)
        With TextBox1
            .SelectionStart = .Text.Length
            .SelectedText = VbCrlf & Date.Now.ToLongTimeString & Chr(9) & msg
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Seems to me that works well, but because understand deeply the GC require lots of time that currently i don't have, i would ask to the community if this Class could be effectively usefull to find memory leaks, as i built it.

Comment: A memory leak is a situation where objects are kept alive despite they are not intended to stay alive. But no-one can check the intention. If there was a way to detect that automatically, all garbage collectors already included it, to free all objects which are intended to be freed.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, i tested and the code works. also link i provided explain that is a method that works. Sometimes when you have thousand of lines of code, could be a quick way to find a leak, don't you think? Did you tested the code if it works?

Comment: When we only had “thousand of lines of code”, we surely didn’t need a memory analyzing tool. Since we don’t have, we surely wouldn’t use a tool that requires modifying the code. Besides that, it’s not possible to test your code, as you didn’t explain what it is supposed to do. Apparently, it’s supposed to record memory usage and draw conclusions from that, which only apply to very simple setups, rather than real life cases.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, for helping. I'm not a professionist developer (probably you had quickly recognised looking at the code), and during the years, while learning, i've add pieces of code to my programs (also rewriting when need)... Now some of my programs have about 40.000 lines of code. I never take care about memory leaks, and now i recognised that somewhere there are lots of leaks. So i'm trying to fix all. But honestly i don't like to buy, install and study a profiler, so i'm trying manually to understand where are the leaks (probably events) and i suppose with this code could be fast...

Comment: The problem with your approach is, that it requires you to know which objects are leaking (or at least have a suspicion) and the time when these objects are supposed to be reclaimable (to assert a memory consumption similar to the point before their allocation). But if you already know these things, you don't need the tool. But real life applications usually aren't that simple, as the life times of the objects overlap, so there is no point where the memory consumption has to be the same as at another point of time. And you still don't know which reference prevents the collection of the object.

Comment: @Holger the code it's made to check for exclusions: you can start it, checking a group of methods, or building a class, or getting values from a different thread. Then when you get an 'area of the code' where it reports leaks, you can restrict the check, placing checkpoint after each method. And then, inside of a method, you can place again different checkpoint. The main point it's that between 2 checkpoint, the code will return the exact memory increment/decrement, because of the GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers consecutive instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Finding mory leaks is not easy. You should reconsider installing 3-rd party SW to detect them. Or use Visual Studio diagnostics tab when debugging.

GC is slow, because it has to do a lot of memory inspections. This class will just tell you if there might be some mory leaks or not. But it will not tell you where to find them.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but did you tested the code if it works? When you say GS it's slow, you mean by ticks? ms? Because the speed of the GC should be relative to machine, OS, free memory, programs priority... Lots of things, as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

Comment: Regarding where to find, why you say so? every 'step' you place, record the memory used in that 'point of the code. So the next will record the memory increment, and the next one will record the amount of memory not released by GC. If you notice in the code i called  GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers

Comment: You can get a lot of false-positive results. Classes used in your code can build desired and persistent inner state. And that will increase used memory.

Comment: Try to measure that class speed (using StopWatch) to see if it's fast enough for you.         GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() takes too much time for regular usage. I suggest you to remove all the code from MemoryLeakTest that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't received many answers, I answer myself.

My problem was that I had a program that started with 25 MB of memory usage, and over time it got to 1.5 GB and then crashed with an 'Out of memory exception'.

Following advices I have:

- I searched for **3rd part software**: but it needs lot of time to study how it works.
- Installed Visual Studio Community 2019, which integrates **Visual
  Studio Diagnostic**, but does not give an immediate and precise location
  of the leaks.
- I studied previous answer about memory leaks on internet: i realized that in general the leaks are due to the incorrect **implementation of the iDisposable interface**.

Through the class I posted in the example, i easily and quickly found the procedures that generated leaks.

Within those procedures, I identified the classes that needed to implement iDisposable, and the parts of code that should be rewritten.

At that point i solved in this mode:

- Implementing iDisposable correctly: foud a brief correct explanation here
  [Implementing IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895856/implementing-idisposable/19896116#19896116)
- Optimizing the Class code, using different constructor to instantiate the instances.

in particular, i replaced this type of code

```
Class MyClass()
    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Friend Inst_of_my_2nd_class As New My2ndClass()
    Friend Inst_of_my_3rd_class As New My3rdClass()
    Friend Inst_of_my_4th_class As New My4thClass()
End Class
```

with this (NB. Not properly sure about code to Dispose instances, with me it seems works well)

```
Class MyClass()
    Implements iDisposable
    Sub New(ByVal ... As some)
        Inst_of_my_2nd_class = New My2ndClass()
    End Sub
    Sub New(ByVal ... As someother)
        Inst_of_my_3rd_class = New My3rdClass()
    End Sub
    Sub New(ByVal ... As someotherelse)
        Inst_of_my_4th_class = New My4thClass()
    End Sub

    Friend Inst_of_my_2nd_class As My2ndClass()
    Friend Inst_of_my_3rd_class As My3rdClass()
    Friend Inst_of_my_4th_class As My4thClass()

#Region "IDisposable Support"
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                ' TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
                ' what to put here: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895856/implementing-idisposable/19896116#19896116
            End If

            ' TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
            ' what to put here: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895856/implementing-idisposable/19896116#19896116

            If Not IsNothing(Inst_of_my_2nd_class) Then
                Inst_of_my_2nd_class.Dispose()
                Inst_of_my_2nd_class = Nothing
            End If
            If Not IsNothing(Inst_of_my_3rd_class) Then
                Inst_of_my_3rd_class.Dispose()
                Inst_of_my_3rd_class = Nothing
            End If
            If Not IsNothing(Inst_of_my_4th_class) Then
                Inst_of_my_4th_class.Dispose()
                Inst_of_my_4th_class = Nothing
            End If

            ' TODO: set large fields to null.
            ' what to put here: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895856/implementing-idisposable/19896116#19896116

        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    ' TODO: override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    '   ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
    '    Dispose(False)
    '    MyBase.Finalize()
    'End Sub

    ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```